# Can I have one onClick function to change different state values in React-js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js and what I want to happen is to have only one function in onClick that can change value of state sampleCount.

This is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    sampleCount: 5,
}
}

firstFunction = () = > {
    this.setState({
        sampleCount: 10
    })
}
secondFunction = () = > {
    this.setState({
        sampleCount: 15
    })
}
thirdFunction = () = > {
    this.setState({
        sampleCount: 20
    })
}
```

and inside return

```
<div>
<button onClick={this.firstFunction}>Button 1 </button>
<button onClick={this.secondFunction}>Button 2 </button>
<button onClick={this.thirdFunction}>Button 3 </button>
<h1>{this.state.sampleCount}</h1>
</div>
```

Is it possible to only use one function that can change the value of state depends on value? and how? Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean by "value" the caption of the Button? And yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap your function in arrow functions:

```
firstFunction = (value) => {
    this.setState({ sampleCount: value})
}

<div>
<button onClick={() => this.firstFunction(5)}>Button 1 </button>
<button onClick={() => this.firstFunction(15)}>Button 2 </button>
<button onClick={() => this.firstFunction(20)}>Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that like this:

```
handleClick = (handleChangeValue) => {
    this.setState({ sampleCount: handleChangeValue })
}
```

And inside return:

```
<div>
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(5)}>Button 1 </button>
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(15)}>Button 2 </button>
<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(20)}>Button 3 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, about the edits.  SO was somehow buggy for me.

Comment: @DavinTryon no problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple examble, Try like this.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
    sampleCount: 5,
    counts:[{buttonName:'button 1', count:10},
            {buttonName:'button 2', count:15}, 
            {buttonName:'button 3', count:20}]
}
}

changeCountFunction = (count) = > {
    this.setState({
        sampleCount: count
    })
}

}
```

and inside return

```
<div>
 {this.state.counts.map((val)=>{
   return <button key={val.count} onClick={()=>this.changeCountFunction(val.count)}>{val.buttonName}</button>
  })}
 </div>
```